# Variadic template with member function pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I've watched several examples online and I don't understand why this doesn't compile..
what I'm trying to do is passed a member function of say class Object, to a class that has a vector of said Objects, and have a function with templated arguments as parameters be called...
example:

```
template <typename ...Args_t>
bool objectsDo(bool (Object::*func)(Args_t...), Args_t&&... args) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < OBJECTS ; ++i) {
        if (!m_objects[i]->*func(std::forward<Args_t>(args)...)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

but every function I try, even a parameterless one I get:

```
error: no instance of function template "objectsDo" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (bool ())
                objectsDo(&Object::close);
```

where my usage is:

```
            objectsDo(&Object::close);
```

EDIT:
as suggested by Columbo, I am now sending the address to the function, but still I get errors when sending with parameters, such as :

```
  error: no instance of function template "objectsDo" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (bool (Object::*)(int, char), int, char)
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? And you're missing a `&` before `Object::close`

Comment: I believe in c++ you don't need that & anymore and it defaults to it, hmm using icc actually but I've done forwarding of variadic templates to c'tors before, I believe it's something with the member fucntion.

Comment: It's not about what you believe. Did you try it with an ampersand? [Compiles fine for me](http://ideone.com/o8ABzF)

Comment: You're right, editted.

Comment: Show us the code. You're obviously doing something wrong somewhere. [This still compiles fine](http://ideone.com/AKZ2Dp).

Comment: for a function taking int and char ?, I just do objectsDo(&Object::blah, someInt, someChar)

Comment: Ahh, got it. Give me a minute.

Comment: -1 for posting a question with sample code that did not match the error quoted.  -1 for changing a question from one problem to another.  Sadly I have but one vote to give, so you get a 50% discount!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you call the function like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i; char c;
    objectsDo(&Object::close, i, c);
}
```

The problem is that the template arguments are deduced inconsequently:

```
template <typename ...Args_t>
bool objectsDo(bool (Object::*func)(Args_t...), Args_t&&... args)
```

`Args_t` is deduced as `int, char` for the first parameter and `int&, char&` for the second. That is because of the internal working of universal references: It works with reference collapsing.

Use another parameter-pack for the trailing parameters :

```
template <typename ...Args_t, typename... Args>
bool objectsDo(bool (Object::*func)(Args_t...), Args&&... args)
{ /* […] */ }
```

Or make the trailing parameter a non-deduced context:

```
template <typename T> struct identity {using type = T;};
template <typename T>
using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

template <typename ...Args_t>
bool objectsDo(bool (Object::*func)(Args_t...), identity_t<Args_t>... args){
    // […]
}
```